# How to create IPC through sockets with a Java client and a Python server?

Tags: java, python, sockets, ipc

I am trying to make two processes communicate through local sockets: a Python **server** and a Java **client**. The data I want to pass between both consists of the **bytes** of a [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) object, with variable size. I want the connection to **remain open** and be used until the end of the program, because I'm passing a lot of objects that need to be processed.

Because Protobuf objects have variable size, I am sending the size of the message/response before sending the true message/response containing the object.

Currently, I am using a TCPServer from the [socketserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) library on the Python side. I have the following handler implemented:

```py
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The request handler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def recv_all(self, n):
        # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
        data = b''
        while len(data) < n:
            packet = self.request.recv(n - len(data))
            if not packet:
                return None
            data += packet
        return data

    def handle(self):
        logger.debug("Beginning of handle cycle for client: {}.".format(self.client_address))

        while True:
            if True: # please disregard this if condition
                # Receive 4 bytes (1 int) denoting the size of the message
                data_length_bytes: bytes = self.recv_all(4)
                logger.debug('Received data_length: {}'.format(data_length_bytes))

                # If recv read an empty request b'', then client has closed the connection
                if not data_length_bytes:
                    break

                data_length: int = int.from_bytes(data_length_bytes.strip(), byteorder='big')
                data: bytes = self.recv_all(data_length).strip()

                response: bytes = data.upper()

                # Send length of response first
                self.request.sendall(len(response).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
                # Send response
                self.request.sendall(response)

                logger.debug(
                    'Sent response to: {}. Size of response: {} bytes. Response: {}.'.format(self.client_address,
                                                                                             len(response),
                                                                                             response))


        logger.debug("End of handle cycle for client: {}.".format(self.client_address))
```

And the following client:

```java
class SocketClient
{
    private static Socket socket;
    private int port;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private DataInputStream in;

    SocketClient(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
        this.createSocket();
    }

    private void createSocket() {
        InetAddress address;
        try {
            address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            this.out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            this.in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    byte[] sendMessageAndReceiveResponse(byte[] messageToSend){
        try {
            if(true) {  // again, please disregard this condition
                //Send the size of the message to the server
                this.out.writeInt(messageToSend.length);
                out.flush();

                this.out.write(messageToSend);
                out.flush();

                //Get the response message from the server
                int length = in.readInt();                    // read length of incoming message

                byte[] buffer = null;
                if(length>=0) {
                    buffer = new byte[length];
                    in.readFully(buffer, 0, buffer.length); // read the message
                }

                return buffer;
            }
        }
        catch (ConnectException exception) {
            System.out.println("ATTENTION! Could not connect to socket. Nothing was retrieved from the Python module.");
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    void close(){
        //Closing the socket
        try
        {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I run the following experiment after starting the Python server:

```java
        SocketClient socketClient = new SocketClient(5000);

        byte[] response;

        // Case 1
        response = socketClient.sendMessageAndReceiveResponse("12345678".getBytes());
        System.out.println(new String(response));

        // Case 2
        response = socketClient.sendMessageAndReceiveResponse("123456781".getBytes());
        System.out.println(new String(response));

        // Case 3
        response = socketClient.sendMessageAndReceiveResponse("12345678123456781".getBytes());
        System.out.println(new String(response));


        socketClient.close();
```

Case 1 and case 3 work well. However, when I run **case 2**, on the Python server side, I get the following log:

```py
DEBUG -- [handle()] Received data_length: b'\x00\x00\x00\t' # The '\t' shouldn't be here. A '\x09' should.
```

And then the server throws and exception and exits the connection. This happens with every string with 8 < length < 14. What am I doing wrong, and is there an easier way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why I was having problems with messages of 8 < length < 14.

I was getting the `\t` character when length was equal to 9. I noticed that if I changed the length to 10, it would become `\n`. And to 13, `\r`. I realized that there wasn't any `\t` magically appearing. Python was for some reason converting `\x09` to `\t`, because the horizontal tab character `\t` has an ASCII code equal to 9!

And when I applied the `strip()` function in this line:

`data_length: int = int.from_bytes(data_length_bytes.strip(), byteorder='big')`

, Python deleted my `\t`, which was actually my `\x09`. My problem was logging the value **before** stripping it, and so I took a long time to figure out my mistake.

Therefore the solution was to simply not use `strip()`. I leave here my current working code (at least for my tests), for someone to use:

Python server handler:

```py
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The request handler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def recv_all(self, n):
        # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
        data = b''
        while len(data) < n:
            packet = self.request.recv(n - len(data))
            if not packet:
                return None
            data += packet
        return data

    def handle(self):
        while True:
            data_length_bytes: bytes = self.recv_all(4)

            # If recv read an empty request b'', then client has closed the connection
            if not data_length_bytes:
                break

            # DON'T DO strip() ON THE DATA_LENGTH PACKET. It might delete what Python thinks is whitespace but
            # it actually is a byte that makes part of the integer.
            data_length: int = int.from_bytes(data_length_bytes, byteorder='big')

            # Don't do strip() on data either (be sure to check if there is some error if you do use)
            data: bytes = self.recv_all(data_length)

            response: bytes = data.upper()

            self.request.sendall(len(response).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
            self.request.sendall(response)
```

The Java client remained the same, but without that `if(true)` condition that I was using for debug reasons.